# Consume JWT token in asp.net core web application

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt

In one of my project need to consume JWT token from asp.net core web application. My trial project is on github https://github.com/SapanPatibandha/JWTAuthentication

This has one server JWTAuthentication which is generating jwt token base on username and password.
Second component is AnyAPI which method is protected by self verification of JWT.
Third important part and where I have problem is Web application.
Need to create login screen in this application, base on this user detail call login api from JWTAuthentication and use that token for all further use of api from that web application.
I am not sure about middleware configuration and how to store this token on web application.

Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, What you asking for is a journey that need some investigating time, that's not what could be answered shortly, so... I'm gonna make this as compact as possible

What you're doing in the repo is hand-generate and validate Jwt Token. If that's required, investigate these stuff:

- Generating Jwt on central identity provider server (which you currently have)
- Validate Jwt on api resource (which you currently comment that out)
- On application(seems like you make use of classic MVC or razor page), create login form that use ajax to get Jwt from identity provider server, store it on client side (browser), then attach it with every request that make use of `AnyAPI`, by cookie or header or something you saw reasonable. Or if you choose to save the token on Server side, implement your own session-Jwt mapping logic(Actually, some kind of Js SPA would be more suitable for this kind of approach).

Another approach would be implement a more proper Oauth implementation. I consider 2 most widely acknowledged in .net ecosystem would be [Identity Server](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [OpenIdDict](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core). Highly recommend to check them out.